# Unity to IOS Xcode ERROR Undefined Symbols ARFoundation /AR

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, arkit, ar-foundation

I have created an own AR Foundation / ARkit Projekt with Unity 2020.3.25f1 for IOS and played it out to Xcode 14.0.

Now I want to build in XCode for Iphone but get the following errors:

```
error build: Undefined symbol: _ARFoundationSamples_GetCurrentThermalState
error build: Undefined symbol: _ARGeoTrackingConfiguration_class
error build: Undefined symbol: _ARSession_addGeoAnchor
error build: Undefined symbol: _DoSomethingWithSession
```

Unfortunately I have not found a solution yet. Same Error with the verifed Unity 2021 Version.  Hope for your help.

Comment: Have the same problem with Xcode 14 and iOS 16.0.2. Seems to happen only with ARFoundation 4.2.6 since the version 4.2.3 works with the mentioned setup using Unity 2021.3.4f1 and Xcode 14 with iOS 16.0.2. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Well I have exactly 1 undefinded symbol - after that the build fails:

error build: Undefined symbol: _UnityARKit_Camera_GetTextureReleaseCallbackHandle

Comment: Hi Danex, i have the same errors / problems also with the newer ARFoundation Version 5x. For me it makes no differences.

Answer (score 0):

I have now found the problem myself. In my Unity-Assets-Scenes folder there was an ARKit folder containing various cs. files that contain the aforementioned code.

I have deleted the folder completely. This solved the problem.

In general, it should be noted that most of the errors I have discovered in Unity could be fixed by simply removing files. In other cases, Unity has simply created the structures again itself and created them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

same problem here ... I have commented out these lines on Unity.XR.ArFoundation.Samples.cpp

/*IL2CPP_EXTERN_C intptr_t DEFAULT_CALL ARGeoTrackingConfiguration_class();
IL2CPP_EXTERN_C void DEFAULT_CALL DoSomethingWithSession(intptr_t);
IL2CPP_EXTERN_C void DEFAULT_CALL ARSession_addGeoAnchor(intptr_t, CLLocationCoordinate2D_t9A0DD6762E16ECA16EEEC69ACFD9644AA0669871, double);
*/

then you will get a couple of compile error , commented them all as well
like this

```
/*intptr_t returnValue = reinterpret_cast<PInvokeFunc>(ARGeoTrackingConfiguration_class)();
 */
return 0;//returnValue;
```

after this it link and run